# freezing the y position of the camera in unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, camera

I am making a plat former game and I'm having a problem in the camera position of the game im imitating the camera movement of the 1st version of the super mario bros but every time I move my character the camera will go up until the character will disappear. How can I fix it?

```
public Transform playerPos;
public Transform rigthCamBoundary;
public Transform levelEnd;

Vector3 destination;
Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

private void Start()
{
    destination = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(levelEnd.position, 22.8f);
    destination = new Vector3(destination.x, destination.y, 13.5f);
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Vector3.Distance(playerPos.position, rigthCamBoundary.position) < 13.7f)
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, levelEnd.position, ref velocity, .14f, 8.5f);
}
```

Comment: Code you gave us is attached to camera or where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To freeze the y-axis, get the y-axis value when the game runs. After using `Vector3.SmoothDamp`, change the y-axis to that variable you got before then apply it to your transform.

```
public Transform playerPos;
public Transform rigthCamBoundary;
public Transform levelEnd;

Vector3 destination;
Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
float yPos;

private void Start()
{
    destination = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(levelEnd.position, 22.8f);
    destination = new Vector3(destination.x, destination.y, 13.5f);

    //Get the default camera y pos
    yPos = transform.position.y;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Vector3.Distance(playerPos.position, rigthCamBoundary.position) < 13.7f)
    {
        Vector3 tempPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, levelEnd.position, ref velocity, .14f, 8.5f);

        //Apply the default camera y pos
        tempPos.y = yPos;
        transform.position = tempPos;
    }
}
```

---

Note that I don't know if this code is attached to the camera but this answer assumes it is. Otherwise the solution still remains the-same but you just have to change `transform.position.y` and `transform.position` to something else.